# Rational Zeros Theorem, get the possible solutions

Tags: rational-numbers

In my book there is a section about rational numbers.

The first example show that:`6^(1/3)` cannot represent a rational number.
In the proof it says that the possible solutions are `±1,±2,±3,±6`. Since that none of these numbers satisfies the equation x^(3)-6=0

The second example show that :`b=((4-2*sqrt(3))/7)^(1/2)` does not represent a rational number.

In the proof it says that the possible solutions of this equation are `±2,±2/7,±2/49,±4,±4/7,±4/49`

My question is: how i arrive to the solutions like  `±2,±2/7,±2/49,±4,±4/7,±4/49` given the equation?

Comment: And do you understand the first statement? To be honest, I don't understand why $\frac{1 817 120 593}{1 000 000 000}$ is not a suspected solution. If I did not know about irrational numbers or I could not count beyond $1 000 000 000$ then I would be convinced that we are talking about 
$6^{\frac{1}{3}}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set $\,x=\sqrt{\dfrac{4-2\sqrt 3\strut}7}$, and eliminate progressively the radicals. You'll obtain the equation:
$$49x^4-56x^2+4=0$$
If $x$  is rational, say $x=\dfrac pq$, $p$  and $q$ coprime, we know $p$ is a divisor of $4$, and $q$ a divisor of $49$, whence the statement.